# How to properly implement a sidebar in Nebular?

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

It displays a blank page when I add sidebar. It does not give me any error messages. If I remove it, it returns to normal.

[Screenshot when I don't add the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDKhi.jpg)
[Screenshot when I added the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1HxN.jpg)

home.component.html

```
<nb-layout windowMode>
    <nb-layout-header fixed>
        <nb-form-field>
            <nb-icon nbPrefix icon="search-outline"></nb-icon>
            <input type="text" nbInput fullWidth shape="round" placeholder="Search">
        </nb-form-field>
        <button nbButton outline shape="round" size="medium" status="primary"><nb-icon icon="plus-outline"></nb-icon>Upload</button>
        <nb-actions>
            <nb-action title="Messages" icon="message-circle-outline" badgeDot badgePosition="top right" badgeStatus="danger"></nb-action>
            <nb-action title="Notifications" icon="bell-outline" badgeDot badgePosition="top right" badgeStatus="danger"></nb-action>
        </nb-actions>
        <nb-user size="medium" name="Tzuyu Chou" picture="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/98/98/c6/9898c6313b8270b8dcc4269c47c3ef9a.jpg"></nb-user>
    </nb-layout-header>
    <nb-sidebar></nb-sidebar>
    <nb-layout-column>Content</nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { NbActionsModule, NbButtonModule, NbContextMenuModule, NbFormFieldModule, NbIconModule, NbInputModule, NbLayoutModule, NbMenuModule, NbSearchModule, NbSidebarModule, NbTabsetModule, NbUserModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbActionsModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbContextMenuModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbSearchModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbFormFieldModule,
    NbInputModule,
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbMenuModule,
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I just want to add a sidebar to my project. I follow the code in the documentation but still, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add NbSidebarService to the list of providers

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [NbSidebarService],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```